# $() function not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function drag_drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); /* Prevent undesirable default behavior while dropping */
    var elem_id = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    event.target.appendChild( document.getElementById(elem_id) );
    $('#app_status').innerHTML = "Dropped "+elem_id+" into the "+event.target.getAttribute('id');
    document.getElementById(elem_id).removeAttribute("draggable");
    document.getElementById(elem_id).style.cursor = "default";
    droppedIn = true;
}
```

This function is working fine but when I update it with jQuery's `$()` method instead of `document.getElementById` it gives a error :

```
index.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at drag_drop (index.js:22)
    at HTMLDivElement.ondrop (index.html?_ijt=ifai0ih42qnjkillablo2ulcln:15)
```

The updated function looks like this:

```
function drag_drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); /* Prevent undesirable default behavior while dropping */
    var elem_id = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    event.target.appendChild( $('#' + elem_id) );
    $('#app_status').innerHTML = "Dropped "+elem_id+" into the "+event.target.getAttribute('id');
    $('#' + elem_id).removeAttribute("draggable");
    $('#' + elem_id).style.cursor = "default";
    droppedIn = true;
}
```

Comment: `$("#app_status").html("Dropped " ... )` — you should find a basic jQuery book or tutorial.

Comment: seems you are mixing `jquery` and `vanilla js`

Comment: app_status is id of element where as elem_id is variable which contain id

Comment: `$()` returns a jQuery object, not an element. You can [get to the element(s)](https://api.jquery.com/get/) from the object, but personally I doubt if you should. Why replace a perfectly working piece of plain JavaScript with a piece of code that is just as long and complex, but in addition requires a thick library?

Comment: The only jQuery reference you will ever need ---> http://api.jquery.com

Comment: To much `jQuery` on `JavaScript` objects ..

Comment: I'm wondering why you are "updating" (subjective) perfectly fine js to jQuery...

Answer (score 1):

Few changes in your code, as per `jQuery`

```
function drag_drop(event) {
   event.preventDefault(); /* Prevent undesirable default behavior while dropping */
   var elem_id = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
   event.target.appendChild( $('#' + elem_id) );

   // ---- **Updated Code**
   $('#app_status').html("Dropped "+elem_id+" into the "+event.target.getAttribute('id'));
   $('#' + elem_id).removeAttr("draggable");
   $('#' + elem_id).css({cursor: "default"});


   droppedIn = true;
}
```

Comment: Did you include `jQuery` any version in your application??? If not then include `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script> is already added

Comment: @AhtishamShahid . Can you explain what you are trying to do here `event.target.appendChild( $('#' + elem_id) );`